# PCA vs. K-means clustering - explained variance

Tags: clustering, pca, multivariate-analysis

Could PCA explained variance be compared with K-means clustering explained variance defined as Between SS/Total SS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Actually both try to minimize a squared reconstruction error.

But in kmeans, all points of the same cluster are represented with the same center, whereas in PCA every point is represented by a lower dimensional coordinate plus a transformation matrix.

So if you just look at the numbers, you are comparing apples and oranges. KMeans can be seen as compression using k.d+n numbers only, whereas PCA uses n.p+d.p if p is the number of components. So PCA will usually be able to get much smaller SSE than KMeans.

Comment: +1. Maybe a bit of qualification about the last sentence would be useful (e.g. k-means with a large number of clusters could conceivably have lower SSE than PCA with a small number of components; or one could imagine a situation with a very large number of points co-located in a smaller number of clusters that are distributed in a high dimensional way)

Comment: Too many corner cases for that. E.g. if we have many copies of just k distinct points, then KMeans will have 0 error, PCA with less than k components may still have some error, and be very redundant.